# Winsock redefinition errors with Bazel

Tags: windows, visual-studio, x86, bazel, winsock

Hello I am building on Windows 10 with Bazel 4.0. I am receiving the following errors.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared\ws2def.h(103): warning C4005: 'AF_IPX': macro redefinition
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(457): note: see previous definition of 'AF_IPX'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared\ws2def.h(144): warning C4005: 'AF_MAX': macro redefinition
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(476): note: see previous definition of 'AF_MAX'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared\ws2def.h(185): warning C4005: 'SO_DONTLINGER': macro redefinition
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(399): note: see previous definition of 'SO_DONTLINGER'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared\ws2def.h(238): error C2011: 'sockaddr': 'struct' type redefinition
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(1007): note: see declaration of 'sockaddr'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared\ws2def.h(440): error C2143: syntax error: missing '}' before 'constant'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared\ws2def.h(440): error C2059: syntax error: 'constant'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared\ws2def.h(494): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '}'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared\ws2def.h(494): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared\ws2def.h(494): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared\ws2def.h(575): warning C4005: 'IN_CLASSA': macro redefinition
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(284): note: see previous definition of 'IN_CLASSA'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared\ws2def.h(581): warning C4005: 'IN_CLASSB': macro redefinition
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(290): note: see previous definition of 'IN_CLASSB'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared\ws2def.h(587): warning C4005: 'IN_CLASSC': macro redefinition
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(296): note: see previous definition of 'IN_CLASSC'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared\ws2def.h(598): warning C4005: 'INADDR_ANY': macro redefinition
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(301): note: see previous definition of 'INADDR_ANY'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared\ws2def.h(600): warning C4005: 'INADDR_BROADCAST': macro redefinition
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(303): note: see previous definition of 'INADDR_BROADCAST'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared\ws2def.h(636): error C2011: 'sockaddr_in': 'struct' type redefinition
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(1011): note: see declaration of 'sockaddr_in'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(136): error C2011: 'fd_set': 'struct' type redefinition
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(1019): note: see declaration of 'fd_set'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(156): warning C4005: 'FD_CLR': macro redefinition
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(94): note: see previous definition of 'FD_CLR'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(171): warning C4005: 'FD_SET': macro redefinition
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(99): note: see previous definition of 'FD_SET'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(180): error C2011: 'timeval': 'struct' type redefinition
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(1035): note: see declaration of 'timeval'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(236): error C2011: 'hostent': 'struct' type redefinition
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(1023): note: see declaration of 'hostent'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(249): error C2011: 'netent': 'struct' type redefinition
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(177): note: see declaration of 'netent'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(256): error C2011: 'servent': 'struct' type redefinition
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(1027): note: see declaration of 'servent'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(268): error C2011: 'protoent': 'struct' type redefinition
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(1031): note: see declaration of 'protoent'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(364): error C2011: 'WSAData': 'struct' type redefinition
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(319): note: see declaration of 'WSAData'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(462): error C2011: 'sockproto': 'struct' type redefinition
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(491): note: see declaration of 'sockproto'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(504): error C2011: 'linger': 'struct' type redefinition
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(1015): note: see declaration of 'linger'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(517): warning C4005: 'SOMAXCONN': macro redefinition
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(541): note: see previous definition of 'SOMAXCONN'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(552): warning C4005: 'FD_READ': macro redefinition
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(559): note: see previous definition of 'FD_READ'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(555): warning C4005: 'FD_WRITE': macro redefinition
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(560): note: see previous definition of 'FD_WRITE'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(558): warning C4005: 'FD_OOB': macro redefinition
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(561): note: see previous definition of 'FD_OOB'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(561): warning C4005: 'FD_ACCEPT': macro redefinition
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(562): note: see previous definition of 'FD_ACCEPT'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(564): warning C4005: 'FD_CONNECT': macro redefinition
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(563): note: see previous definition of 'FD_CONNECT'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(567): warning C4005: 'FD_CLOSE': macro redefinition
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(564): note: see previous definition of 'FD_CLOSE'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(1625): error C2375: 'accept': redefinition; different linkage
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(739): note: see declaration of 'accept'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(1647): error C2375: 'bind': redefinition; different linkage
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(744): note: see declaration of 'bind'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(1668): error C2375: 'closesocket': redefinition; different linkage
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(749): note: see declaration of 'closesocket'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(1685): error C2375: 'connect': redefinition; different linkage
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(751): note: see declaration of 'connect'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(1706): error C2375: 'ioctlsocket': redefinition; different linkage
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(756): note: see declaration of 'ioctlsocket'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(1729): error C2375: 'getpeername': redefinition; different linkage
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(761): note: see declaration of 'getpeername'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(1750): error C2375: 'getsockname': redefinition; different linkage
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(766): note: see declaration of 'getsockname'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(1771): error C2375: 'getsockopt': redefinition; different linkage
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(771): note: see declaration of 'getsockopt'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(1796): error C2375: 'htonl': redefinition; different linkage
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(778): note: see declaration of 'htonl'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(1813): error C2375: 'htons': redefinition; different linkage
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(780): note: see declaration of 'htons'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(1831): error C2375: 'inet_addr': redefinition; different linkage
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(782): note: see declaration of 'inet_addr'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(1849): error C2375: 'inet_ntoa': redefinition; different linkage
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(784): note: see declaration of 'inet_ntoa'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(1949): error C2375: 'listen': redefinition; different linkage
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(786): note: see declaration of 'listen'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(1968): error C2375: 'ntohl': redefinition; different linkage
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(790): note: see declaration of 'ntohl'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(1985): error C2375: 'ntohs': redefinition; different linkage
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(792): note: see declaration of 'ntohs'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(2002): error C2375: 'recv': redefinition; different linkage
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(794): note: see declaration of 'recv'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(2025): error C2375: 'recvfrom': redefinition; different linkage
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(800): note: see declaration of 'recvfrom'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(2052): error C2375: 'select': redefinition; different linkage
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(808): note: see declaration of 'select'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(2077): error C2375: 'send': redefinition; different linkage
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(815): note: see declaration of 'send'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(2100): error C2375: 'sendto': redefinition; different linkage
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(821): note: see declaration of 'sendto'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(2127): error C2375: 'setsockopt': redefinition; different linkage
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(829): note: see declaration of 'setsockopt'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(2152): error C2375: 'shutdown': redefinition; different linkage
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(836): note: see declaration of 'shutdown'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(2172): error C2375: 'socket': redefinition; different linkage
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(840): note: see declaration of 'socket'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(2197): error C2375: 'gethostbyaddr': redefinition; different linkage
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(847): note: see declaration of 'gethostbyaddr'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(2219): error C2375: 'gethostbyname': redefinition; different linkage
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(852): note: see declaration of 'gethostbyname'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(2236): error C2375: 'gethostname': redefinition; different linkage
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(854): note: see declaration of 'gethostname'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(2276): error C2375: 'getservbyport': redefinition; different linkage
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(858): note: see declaration of 'getservbyport'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(2295): error C2375: 'getservbyname': redefinition; different linkage
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(862): note: see declaration of 'getservbyname'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(2314): error C2375: 'getprotobynumber': redefinition; different linkage
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(866): note: see declaration of 'getprotobynumber'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(2331): error C2375: 'getprotobyname': redefinition; different linkage
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(868): note: see declaration of 'getprotobyname'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(2351): error C2375: 'WSAStartup': redefinition; different linkage
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(872): note: see declaration of 'WSAStartup'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(2371): error C2375: 'WSACleanup': redefinition; different linkage
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(876): note: see declaration of 'WSACleanup'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(2388): error C2375: 'WSASetLastError': redefinition; different linkage
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(878): note: see declaration of 'WSASetLastError'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(2405): error C2375: 'WSAGetLastError': redefinition; different linkage
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(880): note: see declaration of 'WSAGetLastError'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(2426): error C2375: 'WSAIsBlocking': redefinition; different linkage
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(882): note: see declaration of 'WSAIsBlocking'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(2444): error C2375: 'WSAUnhookBlockingHook': redefinition; different linkage
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(884): note: see declaration of 'WSAUnhookBlockingHook'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(2462): error C2375: 'WSASetBlockingHook': redefinition; different linkage
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(886): note: see declaration of 'WSASetBlockingHook'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(2480): error C2375: 'WSACancelBlockingCall': redefinition; different linkage
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(888): note: see declaration of 'WSACancelBlockingCall'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(2498): error C2375: 'WSAAsyncGetServByName': redefinition; different linkage
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(890): note: see declaration of 'WSAAsyncGetServByName'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(2526): error C2375: 'WSAAsyncGetServByPort': redefinition; different linkage
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(898): note: see declaration of 'WSAAsyncGetServByPort'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(2554): error C2375: 'WSAAsyncGetProtoByName': redefinition; different linkage
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(906): note: see declaration of 'WSAAsyncGetProtoByName'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(2580): error C2375: 'WSAAsyncGetProtoByNumber': redefinition; different linkage
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(913): note: see declaration of 'WSAAsyncGetProtoByNumber'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(2606): error C2375: 'WSAAsyncGetHostByName': redefinition; different linkage
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(920): note: see declaration of 'WSAAsyncGetHostByName'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(2632): error C2375: 'WSAAsyncGetHostByAddr': redefinition; different linkage
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(927): note: see declaration of 'WSAAsyncGetHostByAddr'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(2662): error C2375: 'WSACancelAsyncRequest': redefinition; different linkage
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(936): note: see declaration of 'WSACancelAsyncRequest'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(2680): error C2375: 'WSAAsyncSelect': redefinition; different linkage
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock.h(938): note: see declaration of 'WSAAsyncSelect'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(4206): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um\winsock2.h(4206): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '}'
```

Reproduction is as follows

file.h

```
#pragma once 

#include "otherfile.h"
```

otherfile.h

```
#pragma once

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
```

What is confusing me is that in all the other posts on this topic say that you can include winsock2 before windows and you should be fine. Let me know if more detail is needed here.

Comment: `winsock2.h` disables `winsock.h` if `winsock2.h` is `#include`'d before `winsock.h`.  But the warnings are clearly suggesting that `winsock.h` is defining things, which means somewhere `winsock.h` is likely being `#include`'d before `winsock2.h`/`ws2def.h`. You may need to define `_WINSOCKAPI_` at the project level to disable `winsock.h` globally.

Comment: Okay Ill try that! Thank you!